# Speedier alternative to spreadsheetaddrows in coldfusion?

Tags: excel, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I'm trying to create excel sheets using coldfusion's spreadsheetaddrows function. Because the tables I'm creating spreadsheets from can be very large, I'm creating the excel file in chunks to avoid timing out the server.  Everything works fine at first, but as the process goes on it really slows down.  For example, I was testing with a table that had 50,000 plus rows and almost 100 columns.  Five hours later, the excel file hadn't even reached 10,000 rows. =T

It seems that spreadsheetaddrows is the problem according to google.  Is there a faster and better way for me to do this?

```
<cfloop index="i" from="#start#" to="#end#" step="10">
<!-- variables -->
<cfset plus = #i# + 9>
<cfif #plus# gt #end#>
<cfset plus = #end#>
</cfif>
<!-- /variables -->


<!-- get i to i+9 records -->
<cfquery name="query" datasource="datasource">
    select *
    from ( select a.*, rownum rnum
           from ( select * from table order by id) a
           where rownum <= #plus# 
         )
    where rnum >= #i#
</cfquery>

<cfif it's the first time doing this>
     <!-- import from database query and save as excel sheet -->
    <cfset spreadsheetAddRows(theSheet, query)>

    <cfif reached the end of the query>
    <cfspreadsheet action = "write"
    overwrite = "true"
    filename = "file.xls" 
    name="theSheet"
    >

    </cfif>

<cfelseif 2nd or more time doing this>
    <!-- add  new rows to excel object -->
    <cfset spreadsheetAddRows(temp, query)>

    <!-- overwrite existing xls file with new data -->
    <cfspreadsheet  action="write"
                    overwrite="true"
                    filename="file.xls"
                    name="temp"
    >  
</cfif>
```

Comment: Did you try `<cfspreadsheet action="write" filename = "something" query="yourQuery">`?  If so, how did that turn out?

Comment: That won't work in my case because I need to update the spreadsheet file multiple times, and I don't think you can update files with the cfspreadsheet tag.

Comment: I've used https://github.com/cfsimplicity/lucee-spreadsheet for spreadsheets with thousands of rows (though not 50k+) and it has performed well.  Might want to give it a shot (also frees you up from being stuck with ACF if you wish to move to Lucee).

Answer (score 0):

I was curious so I tried another approach.  The code below executes successfully and quickly with a small dataset.  For what you are doing, this might still be slow and it might create java heap space problems, but it's probably worth a shot.

First  - Get your query results into a spreadsheet.

```
<cfquery name="dbdata" datasource="dw">
select query goes here
</cfquery>

<cfspreadsheet action="write" overwrite="yes" query="dbdata" filename="#completeFileName#">
```

Then read that spreadsheet, do what you have to do, and update the file.

```
<cfscript>
abc = spreadsheetread(completefilename);
spreadsheetsetcellvalue(abc, 'new value', 2, 1);
spreadsheetwrite(abc, completeFileName, true);
</cfscript>
```

When I opened the file in excel, row 1 had column headers from the query results, and cell A2 contained 'new value'.

Comment: Forgive me for never replying to this!

Comment: Your answer didn't end up working.  I think it still lagged.  What we ended up doing was creating a sql script based on what the user wanted to query and then using cfexecute to run the script and create the spreadsheet.